# Rake task foreign key assignment in a many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables: Group and Keyword. They have a many-to-many relationship via another table called Assignments. I have a rake task where I generate random keywords, save the keyword to the Keyword's table and assign it to the current group's keywords. The code looks like this (I used a similar syntax to what I use in the console; however, I am not sure about it's correctness):

```
Group.populate 30 do |group|        
  Faker::Lorem.words(rand(3..7)).each do |key|
    k = Keyword.create(name: key)
    group.keywords << k
  end 
end
```

The `<<` is returning this error: `NoMethodError: undefined method`<<'`.

If I ran the inner two lines in the console I get what I expect (note: I simplified the below models so you will see more keys in the log, but ignore that):

```
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO "keywords" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "bla"], ["created_at", "2015-03-14 18:25:29.179793"], ["updated_at", "2015-03-14 18:25:29.179793"]]
   (1.2ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Keyword id: 1, name: "bla", created_at: "2015-03-14 18:25:29", updated_at: "2015-03-14 18:25:29">

   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.8ms)  INSERT INTO "assignments" ("group_id", "keyword_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["group_id", 1], ["keyword_id", 1], ["created_at", "2015-03-14 18:26:53.650257"], ["updated_at", "2015-03-14 18:26:53.650257"]]
   (0.8ms)  commit transaction
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Keyword id: 1, name: "bla", created_at: "2015-03-14 18:25:29", updated_at: "2015-03-14 18:25:29">]>
```

The Group model looks like this:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assignments, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :keywords, through: :assignments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

The Keyword model looks like that:

```
class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assignments
    has_many :groups,    through: :assignments 
end
```

And the Assignment model looks like this:

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :group
    belongs_to :keyword
end
```

How can I modify this code to work as expected?

Comment: can you show us your `keyword` and `group` `model`  code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in my program. Even though it was a stupid mistake from me, I will leave the question and the error reported in case anybody fall into the same issue in the future. 
I had this error because I had a field in my Group table which is named keywords, which of course conflicted with the Keywords table (which has many-to-many relation to Groups). I had this field from before I decided to create the many-to-many relation, and I forgot to remove it. Then, of course when you type something like this command `group.keywords << Keyword.create(name: key)` you will get this weird error: `NoMethodError: undefined method<<`.

However, fixing this mistake will not make the rake task run. This is because `Group.populate` returns a Populator object. If you run this task you will get this error: `NoMethodError: undefined method keywords for #<Populator::Record:0x007fa1ee78fba8>`. To fix that issue I had to assign the foreign keys manually in the task like so:

```
Group.populate 30 do |group|        
   Faker::Lorem.words(rand(3..7)).each do |key|
        k = Keyword.create(name: key)
        a = Assignment.create(keyword_id: k.id, group_id: group.id)
   end 
end
```

which will run as expected.

Answer (score 0):

TRy this

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :active_assignments, dependent: :destroy, class_name: "Assignment"
  has_many :keywords, through: :active_assignments, source: :keyword

class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assignments, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :groups, through: :assignments
end 

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :group
    belongs_to :keyword
end    


Group.populate 30 do |group|        
   Faker::Lorem.words(rand(3..7)).each do |key|
      group.keywords << Keyword.create(name: key)
   end 
end
```

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `create' for nil:NilClass

Comment: sorry the keyword_assignment was my bad. I forgot to modify it when I wrote the simplified code above, but it is not the issue.

Comment: no it is not working, it is giving the error I posted: undefined method `create' for nil:NilClass

Comment: now it is exactly like my above code, or? (I get the same error as before)

Comment: I get this error:
SyntaxError: /Users/sam/Documents/projects/web-projects/rails-projects/Forsker/app/models/group.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected =>
 has_many :assignments, dependent: => :destroy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73000/discussion-between-salah-saleh-and-sontya).